# typing text in beamer

Tags: beamer, math-mode, type

After downloading the latest version of MikTex, i type maths and it gives me satisfactory outcome. But when i first type the title, author etc...it gives me nothing! Do i have to use another \usepackage or \usetheme command?      This is the code I use:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usetheme{Warsaw}
\title{Asymptotic Safety and Reduction of Couplings}
\author{I.Sklavounos}
\institute{National Technical University of Athens}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{outline}
Asymptotic Safety\\
Standard Model with Gravity Contributions\\
Reduction of Couplings\\
Conclusion
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
$$\mu\frac{\partial g_i}{\partial \mu}=\beta_{i}(g)$$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I compile your code and it works as expected. What do you think is missing? If you expected a separate frame with the title and author name, you need to add `\frame{\titlepage}`.

Comment: Those commands `\title`,`\author`,`\institute`, `\date` was just define the variable. To make a output, you need use `\maketitle`.

Comment: I use the miktex 22.3x64 version, and it gives me correctly what lies beneath the \begin{document} command. Everything else before: title,author,institute,date doesn't

Comment: Maybe i have to add another command more appropriate for this version of miktex?

Answer (score 0):

Everything before `\begin{document}` was called preamble. Everything you type before that won't make output in your document. As I said in comment, those commands `\title`,`\author`,`\institute`, `\date` was just define the variable. To make a output for these variables in your document, you need use `\maketitle` after `begin{document}`. According to the comment from @Zarko, I comment the packages that don't need to be explicitly loaded in beamer:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\usepackage{graphicx}% already include in beamer
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{multirow}
%\usepackage{amssymb}% already include in beamer
%\usepackage{amsmath}% already include in beamer

\usetheme{Warsaw}
\title{Asymptotic Safety and Reduction of Couplings}
\author{I.Sklavounos}
\institute{National Technical University of Athens}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{outline}
Asymptotic Safety\\
Standard Model with Gravity Contributions\\
Reduction of Couplings\\
Conclusion
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
$$\mu\frac{\partial g_i}{\partial \mu}=\beta_{i}(g)$$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You nod need to load `graphicx` and `amsmath` in preamble. This already do `beamer`.

Comment: @Zarko I didn't know that. Thank you for pointing out. I guess `\usepackage{amssymb}` is also not needed?

Comment: You can test this yourself ;-). It is needed, if presentation content contain symbols defined in `amsymb`.

Comment: @Zarko I can use `\mathbb` without load `amssymb`. Which means it was already included, right?

Comment: Yes, also load this package. If you like use its symbols from some other package, you shoud use `beamer` as `\documentclass[noamssymb]{beamer}` (see package documentation, pp.120)

Comment: Thank you all! You have been very helpfull! It finally works!!!!

Comment: @IoannisSklavounos If this answer solved your issue, you should upvote it and mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: How am i doing that? How do i mark an answer as the correct one? and also, i would like to ask if i want to post a question, i wriite the main part of it, then i go to the tag, and it shows me, that my question can't be submitted and it guides me to the popular tags. How do i mark a tag from the existed ones and put it on my tag? Thanks

Comment: @Ioannis There is a `checkmark` beside the answer on the top left corner which can be used for marking this answer as the correct one. For the tag stuff, I am not quite sure what is your question. Usually you can type some key words and system  will pop-up some suggestions for you. You can choose one from it. Is this what you ask?

Comment: @Tom,Ok, i will mark the answer as you say, thank you. What i am saying about the tag stuff, is that when i write on it, it usually it tells me that i should use some tags from the existed ones, because it drops me out of it, usually, it says that i need more score on reputation. I want to add on the tag i write in appropriate manner, how do i do that, how the tag i write wll be accepted? in order my question to be submitted?

Comment: @Ioannis you mean add new tag by yourself? I think you need 300 reputation in order to do that. I have never done that before. You can check this link. https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags

Comment: @Tom, i mean to add one from the existed ones. When i click on the ?, it drives me to other tags. How can i choose on from them, in order to fullfil the tad command properly?

Comment: I suspect that i somehow  have to click on something in order for my tag to be accepted.

Comment: @Ioannis I think you just left click them. How you add them in this question?

Comment: @Tom, ok, i will try it, thanks!